# Android slide out menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-menu

Where can I find a good working example of slide out menu in android? I did go through the official samples. Wanted something a tad better than that.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example, it is working fine for me -

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/